# Controlling evaluation depth in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, evaluation

I want to control the depth of the evaluations in Mathematica. For instance, consider the following simple code:

`y := 3.x

z := 4.y

v := 5.z`

Now, sometimes when I type v I would like Mathematica to replace z by its value, but not y by its value (that is, v = 20 y and not v = 60 x). And sometimes I want Mathematica to replace all variables. I've been playing around with different functions in Mathematica (such as Hold) but the only way I could find is using assignment rules (i.e. y-> 3x and so on). Is there a simpler/better way to do it? I've been searching for the answer to my fairly simple question but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to define functions :

```
y[x_] := 3. x
z[y_] := 4. y
v[z_] := 5. z

v[z[y]]
(* 20. y *)

v[z[y[x]]]
(* 60. x *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew there should be a simple solution. Thanks again!